# php sql server driver for windows 8

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, windows

Is there a way on how to connect php sql server driver on **windows 8**. I'm using **php 5.5.6** version but It seems sql Driver doesn't support on Windows 8 for php. In the System Requirements for sql Driver the Windows 8 is not included. I installed and configured sql driver for php on xampp server but sqlsrv doesn't working. I already install **extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll** and also **php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll** but they both give me a message:

Using php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll:

```
PHP Startup: pdo_sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module 
Module compiled with modue API=xxxxxx 
PHP compile with module API=zzzzzz
These options need to match
```

Using php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll:

```
PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module 
Module compiled with modue API=xxxxxx 
PHP compile with module API=zzzzzz
These options need to match
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved installing PHP version `5.4.7`, downloading a new version of the driver:

```
Version: 3.1
File Name: SQLSRV31.EXE
Date Published: 05/11/2014
```

[Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

and adding in `php.ini`:

```
extension = php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```